# SMS posts from Google Voice to Google+ don't work any more

Tags: google-plus, google-voice

Posts from Google Voice to Google+ via SMS are not working.

For good measure, I tried testing from another Google Voice account and changed the SMS source number in Google+ settings. Did not work. I then tried provisioning access for my cell phone and tested from there.  Works fine.

So at this point, here's what I know:

- G+ SMS updates from mobile phone works.
- G+ SMS updates from google voice fails.
- Other SMS updates from google voice are sent/received fine.
- I'm not getting any errors.

This leads me to believe that G+ administratively blocks Google Voice SMS updates.  Any suggestions on how to fix this? I've already opened a forum post with Google+ but no official response yet.  This is definitely affecting other people - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plus-discuss/HxlC9BnrHiw/3W5-ZK16BpoJ